# How to name a method () like scala's Map

Tags: scala

I'm writing a database access service. Different services will return a different object stored in the database somehow. I'd like to model my access methods like those on Map.

```
trait DatabaseAcess[T] {

def get(id: String): Option[T]

def getOrElse(id: String, default: => T): T = get(id).getOrElse(default)

def ()(id: String) = get(id).getOrElse(throw new Exception(s"can't get $id"))
}
```

I'm a super n00b here. How can I make the () work?

Comment: def apply(id: String)

Comment: @EugeneZhulenev thanks. I thought apply was only for alternative constructors. Good to know. If you make your comment an answer I'll up-vote and accept.

Comment: meaning I'm used to apply in this context: case class A(x: Int) object A{ def apply(x: Double): A = A(x.toInt) }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your method as

```
def apply(id: String) = get(id).getOrElse(throw new Exception(s"can't get $id"))
```